# Alternate for onSupportNavigateUp of activity in fragment with single activity and navigation componnet

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I am using `onSupportNavigateUp()` in activity and now i am moving to use single activity architecture and navigation component problem is that i stuck here i don't find any elternative to `onSupportNavigateUp()` and `onBackPressed()` in `fragment` and `navcontroller`

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    // some code like showing ad
    onBackPressed()
    return super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

but i find solution solution `onBackPressed()` with `onBackPressedDispatcher` but problem is that is only work when navigation bar back button pressed not for toolbar up button

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
             // some code like showing ad
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

for me, that work is you have set up navigation component with toolbar like this

```
toolbar.setupWithNavController(findNavController())

toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            // some code
            findNavController().navigateUp()
        }
```